# TypeError: Column is not iterable when using more than one columns in withColumn()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to find quarter start date from a date column. I get the expected result when i write it using selectExpr()

```
df.selectExpr("add_months(history_effective_month,-(month(history_effective_month)%3)+1) as history_effective_qtr","history_effective_month").show(5)

output-

history_effective_qtr   history_effective_month

       2017-07-01                2017-06-01
       2016-04-01                2016-05-01
       2015-10-01                2015-09-01
       2012-01-01                2012-01-01
       2012-01-01                2012-01-01
```

but when i add the same logic in .withColumn() i get TypeError: Column is not iterable

```
df.withColumn("history_effective_quarter",add_months('history_effective_month',-(month('history_effective_month')%3)+1))

TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) 
<ipython-input-259-0bb78d27d2a7> in <module>() 1 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/column.py in iter(self) 248 249 def iter(self): --> 250 raise TypeError("Column is not iterable") 251 252 # string methods

TypeError: Column is not iterable
```

I am using a workaround as follows

```
df=selectExpr('*',"date_sub(history_effective_date," \
   "dayofmonth(history_effective_date)-1) as history_effective_month")
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** Just  use [`select`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=select#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn):

> `select(*cols)`
>
> Projects a set of expressions and returns a new DataFrame.

```
df.select(
   "history_effective_quarter", add_months('history_effective_month',
   -(month('history_effective_month')%3)+1))
```

Your code cannot work because [`withColumn`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=select#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn):

> `withColumn(colName, col)`
>
> Returns a new DataFrame by adding a column or replacing the existing column that has the same name.

is used to add a single column